# What's the rule of thumb to keep data safe in portable SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, file-corruption

I am well aware that SSDs in general are not ideal medium as long term shelf storage.
But if one insists on using it for that purpose, what can be done to keep files stored in SSD corrupt-free, other than temperature control?

Especially, is it enough to just plug it in to computer once in a while to reestablish the perfect condition like it used to be when in use? and for how long to keep it plugged in before sending it back to shelf?

I've asked around but nothing seems to be so clear on this.

So here I am. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For SSDs and HDDs it is best to periodically read all stored data as data corruption is usually only detected when data is read. On SSDs the controller may read data while the drive is idle (not sure if this really happens) but it is better to make sure and just force data reading from a PC.